# Rails numerate records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a list of records with `number` attribute.

- Invoice(user_id: 1, number: nil)
- Invoice(user_id: 1, number: nil)
- Invoice(user_id: 2, number: nil)
- Invoice(user_id: 3, number: nil)

My desired result is:

- Invoice(user_id: 1, number: 001)
- Invoice(user_id: 1, number: 002)
- Invoice(user_id: 2, number: 001)
- Invoice(user_id: 2, number: 002)

Tried:

```
    Invoice.all.each do |i|
     i.number = "#{sprintf '%03d', i.user.invoices.count + 1}"
     i.save
    end
```

But got the current result:

- Invoice(user_id: 1, number: 002)
- Invoice(user_id: 1, number: 002)
- Invoice(user_id: 2, number: 003)
- Invoice(user_id: 2, number: 003)

How do I get the desired result? Thanks

Comment: What is your DB?

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk, mysql

Comment: You need window functions to do it _effective_: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Comment: I have no MySQL, but can provide example for PostgreSQL, which is very close.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk, to be honest, I would like to use ActiveRecord

Comment: Ok, you have solution from Muhammad. When you get 1k+ invoices, come back for effective solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
    User.all.each do |user|
      number = 1
      user.invoices.order(:id).each do |i|
       i.number = "#{sprintf '%03d', number}"
       i.save
       number +=1
      end
    end
```

Comment: This is very _ineffective_ solution.

Comment: Ineffective or inefficient? Seems a one time operation to me. & on each new invoice handle number on runtime.

Comment: Given: 10K invoices from 3-5K users. Count SQL queries and memory consumption by ActiveRecord.